# Docker. PostgreSQL. Can't connect to db into container

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I'm new in docker and PostgreSQL. I want run postgreSQL into docker container and work with it via my app. I used installation [guide](https://selectel.ru/blog/postgresql-docker-setup/). What I did:

1. install docker
2. got postgresql image from docker hub
3. ran container

```
sudo docker run --rm --name geo_pg_docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=340354 -e POSTGRES_USER=geo_db_user -e POSTGRES_DB=geo_db -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

4. checked conteiner `sudo docker ps`
   [image]
5. tried to connect `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U geo_db_user -d geo_db`
6. entered password 340354 and got
   [image]

At first time, it worked propperly. But after installing Docker Desctop (it doesn't work) and reboot system everething goes wrong. I cannot imagine what's wrong
I use Ubunut 22.04 LTS.

Comment: probably not a helpful answer but is there a reason why you use docker desktop on a linux ? i'm curious

Comment: The reason is I'm new and it's my habit use window app from win system. Is it wrong, use docker desktop in linux?

Comment: Why are these commands producing images out?  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual text of your error message instead of the images?  Are you running that `psql` command from the host or another container?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

1. [Remove Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/#uninstall-docker-desktop)
2. [Remove Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine)
3. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

Everething is OK.